# How to use .iso file downloaded inside oracle virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox

I downloaded .iso file  INSIDE oracle virtual box and it is  stored in Downloads directory of VB. I can not find a way to use it  nor can I  copy it OUTSIDE VB. I use Ubuntu 18.04 .Anyone  knows solution?

Comment: Your don't have guest additions installed? :) If not your system is sandboxed and the only exit is USB, online storage or dvd/cd writer. Install Vbox Guest additions and you can copy files outside of vbox

Comment: Well, I tried but obviously did not succeed well. Do you have some instruction how to dio it? I have DVD writer but  how to write this .iso file to it from VB?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=ubuntu+guest+additions&oq=ubuntu+guest+additions&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7169j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 should have all you need ;)

Comment: I have Tilix and GNOME Terminal 3.28.2  . How to get 6.06.1 Dapper Drake release mentioned in the article ?

Comment: ERROR  when trying to : ( there is no option INSTALL GUEST ADDITIONS :

Unable to insert the virtual optical disk /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine debian1.



Could not mount the media/drive '/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
Callee: IMachine {85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89}

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

- network shared folder [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)
- connect usb and add it to the vm [link](https://superuser.com/questions/87221/how-can-i-mount-an-external-hard-drive-in-a-virtualbox-machine)
- copy with scp
- ftp server [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- run web server from the folder containing .iso file `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

All except for flash drive options can be used on both host and client.